# Kafka Sticky Partitioner using spring cloud stream

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using spring cloud stream for Kafka consumer/producer.

We have multiple producers which defined with:

```
producer:
  partitionKeyExpression: payload.partitionKey
```

As well we do have producers without such definition, which seems it's using the default partitioner.

Is the sticky partitioner will take place in cases that payload.paritionKey is null?
Is the default partitioner, when no patitionKeyExpression / header are defined will set paritionKey as null and the sticky paritioner will take place?

Comment: Here is a blog that goes into the details of producer partitions in the Kafka binder: https://spring.io/blog/2021/02/03/demystifying-spring-cloud-stream-producers-with-apache-kafka-partitions. You might want to read that on some additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no `partitionKeyExpression`, the partition will be determined by the `KafkaProducer`.

Look at the INFO log for the producer config. The default partitioner is

```
partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
```

You can configure whatever partitioner you want via the binder or binding properties.